# Form path not correctly showing defined path in view - rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So lets say I have an Author Model
Authors has_many Books

For all intents and purposes, lets say I have a totally random controller, like XYZ with the action index.

The index view - shows a single Author (this is hard defined in this example - lets say its something like `@author = Author.find(1)`

Ok, on the view here, we have a form, for adding new books to the author.

The routes look something like so:

```
resources author do
   resources book
end
```

The form for adding books looks like so:

(@book = Book.new)

```
<%= form_for new_author_book_path(:author, @book) do |reg_form| %>
```

However, when I view the HTML, the form says its posting to `action="/XYZ/index"`

It obviously does not work when I submit the form..

Whats going on here exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `form_for` should look more like:

```
<%= form_for [@author, @book] do |reg_form| %>
```

Controller:

```
@author = Author.find(1)
@book = @author.books.build
```

The `new_author_book_path` helper is a GET request (i.e. authors/1/books/new)